# Reading binary data through stdin with cat command on linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to read binary data through stdin (0) to my program using `cat` command. My program's task is to change binary to integer or double and write it to the desired file descriptor. 
When I run the command: `cat data_int.bin | ./myprogram -d`, I can not read anything and also the size of input is 0. But when i try: `./myprogram -d -I 0     0<data_int.bin`, my program can read bytes and succesfully finish.


My code:

```
#libraries

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        int c;
        extern char *optarg;
        extern int optind;
        extern int optopt;

        char input_file[100] = { 0 };
        int nastavljen_input = 0;
        char output_file[100] = { 0 };
        int nastavljen_output = 0;
        int tip = -1; // 0 - char, 1- int, 2 - double
        int fd_in = 0;
        int fd_out = 1;
        while((c = getopt(argc,argv, ":o:i:O:I:cdf")) != -1) {
            switch(c) {
                case 'o':
                    strcpy(output_file,optarg);
                    nastavljen_output = 1;
                    fd_out = open(output_file,O_WRONLY);
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    strcpy(input_file,optarg);
                    nastavljen_input = 1;
                    fd_in = open(input_file,O_RDONLY);
                    break;
                case 'O':
                    fd_out = atoi(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    fd_in = atoi(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    tip = 0;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    tip = 1;
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    tip = 2;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(tip > -1) {
            struct stat st;
            fstat(fd_in, &st); //fd_in would be 0 with cat command
            int size = st.st_size; // number of bytes in input file
            printf("%d\n",size); // this will print out 0 with cat command

            unsigned char buffer[size];
            read(fd_in,buffer,size);

            ...code continues...
```

Flag -d is for reading bytes representing integers and -I is for choosing input file descriptor. Output is stdout(1) in this case.


My question is, it there a problem with my code or is this just the way `cat` command works? I am using Xubuntu.

Thank you for your time and effort,
Domen

Comment: Related: [UNIX/Linux IPC : Reading from a pipe. How to know length of data at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151029/unix-linux-ipc-reading-from-a-pipe-how-to-know-length-of-data-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes always have `st_size` 0, because the length of the stream of bytes that will be written into a pipe is not known ahead of time.

There are many programs that behave differently on `cat foo | prog` and `prog < foo`. This is the reason. In the second case, `prog` has a regular file on stdin so `stat` reveals the size. Also in the second case, `lseek`/`fseek` will work, and on the pipe it won't.

If you want to read the contents of a stdin into a buffer, and you need that to work when stdin is a pipe, you have to guess a size for it, and then keep track of how much you read and when you run out of memory, allocate some more. `realloc` is good for this.

Comment: i changed buffer size to 20 and read nbytes to 20. still, I get nothing... 20 is the complete size of binary file.

Comment: ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte) - I set nbyte to 20 and size of buffer to buffer[20].

Comment: @domenkavran When I do that, `read` returns 20 as you'd expect.

Comment: @thatotherguy my bad. this works. But my next problem is how to determine or change size of buffer while executing? The reallocation can be too big.

Comment: Why do you need to read the entire file into memory before converting it? Can't you convert 8 bytes at a time or whatever?